# JQuery Mobile validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have this form, which works fine. After submitting the input fields are written down on a MySQL Database. So in the next step I want to mark all fields as required. I want to integrate the validation script of this site: http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/

However, it does not work. The form is submitted without any validation. Here is the form

```
<form id="form-haftpflicht" method="post">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="versicherungsbeginn"><b>Versicherungsbeginn</b></label>
                <input type="date" name="versicherungsbeginn" id="versicherungsbeginn" value="" />
    </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="erwachsene" class="select"><b>Anzahl Erwachsene:</b></label>
    <select name="erwachsene" id="erwachsene" data-role="none" >
        <option value="" data-placeholder="true">-- Bitte wählen --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="kinder" class="select"><b>Anzahl Kinder:</b></label>
    <select name="kinder" id="kinder" data-role="none" >
        <option value="" data-placeholder="true">-- Bitte wählen --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend><b>Besitzverhältnisse</b></legend>
     <input type="radio" name="besitzverhaltnisse" id="mieter" value="Mieter" checked="checked" />
     <label for="mieter">Mieter</label>
     <input type="radio" name="besitzverhaltnisse" id="eigentumer" value="Eigentumer" />
     <label for="eigentumer">Eigentümer</label>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="garantiesumme"><b>Garantiesumme in CHF</b></label>
                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="garantiesumme" id="garantiesumme" value="" />
                </fieldset>
        </div>
               <div data-role="fieldcontain">
           <h3>Meinde Daten</h3>
           <p>Bitte geben Sie hier Ihre Personalien ein, damit wir die Offerte erstellen können.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                        <legend></legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="geschlecht" id="geschlecht_mann" value="mann" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="geschlecht_mann">Mann</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="geschlecht" id="geschlecht_frau" value="frau" />
                    <label for="geschlecht_frau">Frau</label>
                </fieldset><br>
                <label for="vornamen"><b>Vornamen:</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="vornamen" id="vornamen" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="nachnamen"><b>Nachnamen:</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="nachnamen" id="nachnamen" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="adresse"><b>Adresse:</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="plz8"><b>PLZ</b></label>
                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"  name="plz8" id="plz8" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="gemeinde8"><b>Ort</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="gemeinde8" id="gemeinde8" value="" readonly />
                <br>
                <label for="kanton8"><b>Kanton</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="kanton8" id="kanton8" value="" readonly />
                <br>
                <label for="geburtsdatum"><b>Geburtsdatum</b></label>
                <input type="date" name="geburtsdatum" id="geburtsdatum" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="nationalitat"><b>Nationalität:</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="nationalitat" id="nationalitat" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="telefon"><b>Telefon</b></label>
                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="telefon" id="telefon" value="" />
                <br>
                <label for="email"><b>E-Mail</b></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
               </div>
            </form>
```

And here is my original submit script with the api

```
  $(document).ready(function () {



            $("#store-haftpflicht").click(function () {
                $("#form-haftpflicht").submit();
            });
            $("#form-haftpflicht").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "block");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/store_haftpflicht.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "none");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

and finally here is the validation script, which I have form the website mentioned above

```
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

// just for the demos, avoids form submit
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
      debug: true,
      success: "valid"
    });
    $( "#form-haftpflicht" ).validate({
      rules: {
        versicherungsbeginn: {
          required: true
        },
              erwachsene: {
          required: true
        },
              kinder: {
          required: true
        },
              besitzverhaltnisse: {
          required: true
        },
              garantiesumme: {
          required: true
        },
              geschlecht: {
          required: true
        },
              vornamen: {
          required: true
        },
              nachnamen: {
          required: true
        },
              adresse: {
          required: true
        },
              plz8: {
          required: true
        },
                  gemeinde8: {
          required: true
        },

                  kanton8: {
          required: true
        },

                  geburtsdatum: {
          required: true
        },
                      nationalitat: {
          required: true
        },

                      telefon: {
          required: true
        },

                      email: {
          required: true
        }


      }
    });
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle out of this ?

Comment: here it is, but without my submit script. just validation script and the form - https://jsfiddle.net/lovarano/t6y485kq/

Comment: Hi again, now the validation works, but the problem is the form is submitted anyway. I think I have first do the validation and then submit the form. Maybe I have to implement it in the submit script

Comment: hey. the fiddle does not work. Have you included the validation library ?

Comment: Hi Ankur I couldn't include it. However, I tried to combine both scripts, but still I have issues. Here is my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560765/jquery-ajax-validation-before-submit-is-not-working