# JQuery/Ajax: Validation before submit is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have this script, which works without validation before. I inserted the validation script and since them I does not work. What I did wrong? Also the data from the form are not transferred to the MYSQL Database. I posted also my previous script without validation and the validation script seperately below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


// just for the demos, avoids form submit
$jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#form-haftpflicht" ).validate({
  rules: {
    versicherungsbeginn: {
      required: true
    },
          erwachsene: {
      required: true
    },
          kinder: {
      required: true
    },
          besitzverhaltnisse: {
      required: true
    },
          garantiesumme: {
      required: true
    },
          geschlecht: {
      required: true
    },
          vornamen: {
      required: true
    },
          nachnamen: {
      required: true
    },
          adresse: {
      required: true
    },
          plz8: {
      required: true
    },
          gemeinde8: {
      required: true
    },
         kanton8: {
      required: true
    },
        geburtsdatum: {
      required: true
    },
        nationalitat: {
      required: true
    },
        telefon: {
      required: true
    },
         email: {
      required: true
    }

  },



            $("#store-haftpflicht").click(function () {
                $("#form-haftpflicht").submit();
            });
            $("#form-haftpflicht").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "block");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/store_haftpflicht.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "none");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
                    }
                });
            });

            });
        });
```

Here is my code, which worked fine since validation before:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#store-haftpflicht").click(function () {
            $("#form-haftpflicht").submit();
        });
        $("#form-haftpflicht").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "block");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/store_haftpflicht.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (data, status) {
                    $("#ajax-loader").css("display", "none");
                },
                error: function () {
                    output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and here the validation script, which I tried to integrate in the submit script.

```
$jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#form-haftpflicht" ).validate({
  rules: {
    versicherungsbeginn: {
      required: true
    },
          erwachsene: {
      required: true
    },
          kinder: {
      required: true
    },
          besitzverhaltnisse: {
      required: true
    },
          garantiesumme: {
      required: true
    },
          geschlecht: {
      required: true
    },
          vornamen: {
      required: true
    },
          nachnamen: {
      required: true
    },
          adresse: {
      required: true
    },
          plz8: {
      required: true
    },
          gemeinde8: {
      required: true
    },
         kanton8: {
      required: true
    },
        geburtsdatum: {
      required: true
    },
        nationalitat: {
      required: true
    },
        telefon: {
      required: true
    },
         email: {
      required: true
    }

  },
});
```

Comment: did you get any JS console errors?

Comment: No I have no errors in the console.

Comment: May we see your HTML?

Comment: here is the link to the form. it is a jquery mobile app - http://app.lovanet.ch/phonegap/app/www/index.html#p14